# Redux - how do i access the app state from sub-components?

Tags: redux

Let's say i have the following components structure:

> App -> Comp1 -> Comp2 -> Comp3 -> Comp4 -> Comp5

Where `App` is the parent component of `Comp1` which is the parent component of `Comp2` and so on.

I create the `store` in `App` and connect it to `Comp1` with the "connect" function from the "react-redux" library.

Now, what do i do if i want to access the app state or dispatch an action from `Comp5`?

The way i'm aware of is to pass the props (state and dispatch) all the way from `App` too `Comp5` which doesn't seem to intuitive.

What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

With `Redux` forgot the  `component hierarchy` you can connect the `store` directly to your component `comp5`:

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";

    const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
      return {
        ...state.getExampleReducer,
        ...ownProps
      };
    };

    const mapDispatchToProps = {
     ActionsFunctions
    };

    export default connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      mapDispatchToProps
    )(comp5);
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! So i'd have to define and connect `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` in every component i want to access the store?

Comment: just after connecting your component with the store you will find all the information passed as props so you can access to it easily.